# C: strtok() delimeter loop randomly failing

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-mkr1000

I am splitting a string (with weather information):

```
1:7.34:7.54:87.62:1012.33
```

Which is: message type, temperature, inside temperature, humidity and barometric pressure

```
  if (rf69.available()) {
  uint8_t buf[RH_RF69_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
  uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
  if (rf69.recv(buf, &len)) {

  if (!len) return;
  buf[len] = 0;

  Serial.print("Received [");
  Serial.print(len);
  Serial.print("]: ");
  Serial.println((char*)buf);
  Serial.print("RSSI: ");
  Serial.println(rf69.lastRssi(), DEC);

  char* data;
  data = (char*)buf;
  char separator[] = ":";
  char *array[4]; //4
  int i=0;
  array[i] = strtok(data,separator);
  if( array[i][0] == '1' && array[i][1] == 0 ) {
    while( i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) && array[i] != NULL)  { 
      array[i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
      Serial.println(array[i]);
      i++ ;
    }
  }

  char* t1 = array[0];
  char* t2 = array[1];
  char* h = array[2];
  char* p = array[3];
  Serial.print("Temperature Outside= "); Serial.print(t1);
  Serial.print(" Temperature Enclosure= "); Serial.print(t2);
  Serial.print(" Rel. Humidity =  "); Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(" Pressure = "); Serial.println(p);
}
```

}

The correct result is:

```
Received [25]: 1:7.33:7.51:87.53:1012.32
RSSI: -60
7.33
7.51
87.53
1012.32 
Temperature Outside= 7.33 Temperature Enclosure= 7.51 Rel. Humidity =  87.53 Pressure = 1012.32
```

But at random times i seem to get this:

```
Received [25]: 1:7.33:7.50:87.60:1012.33
RSSI: -60
7.33
Temperature Outside= 7.33 Temperature Enclosure=  Rel. Humidity =   Pressure =  ⸮
```

As you can see the original date seems fine, but it fails processing at random times.
I don't see anything obvious, but i am also not a C expert.

Comment: What is `buf`? Why do you do `data = (char*)buf`? Can't you use `buf` directly (well you still do since you don't copy the contents of `buf`, whatever it is)?

Comment: hi, i thought it wasnt important, but i have added it now :) it is an input from an RF69 radio. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: On an unrelated note, `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)` will *always* be equal to `4`.

Comment: What prints `Received [25]: 1:7.33:7.51:87.53:1012.32`?

Comment: The code presented in the question does not appear capable of producing the output attributed to it.  I don't see anything in it that would print the "Received" line, and that's definitely relevant to the question.

Comment: sorry guys i missed a part on my last edit :) @JohnBollinger

Comment: Now the code presented ought to print stuff that does not appear in the output presented.  What we're looking for in an MRE is not code and output that merely happen to be aligned. Rather, it is code that reproduces the problem and output produced *by that code*.  Otherwise, the example output is worthless.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the code above should be correct now. The received part is what is the input from the strtok (initially buf), the output is printed below the code, what is should be and what i get. As i stated earlier the output fails about 1 out of 20 times. all of these times the buf data that is printed is OK, but not the processed data from strtok. (last example)

Comment: `buf[len] = 0;` could be beyond. (len can be `sizeof buff` here)

Comment: To make it fail consistently, change `char *array[4];` to `char *array[4] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};`

Comment: could you explain what you mean @wildplasser?

Comment: @user3386109 i want it to work all the time, why do i want to always make it fail?

Comment: When dealing with an intermittent bug (that occurs 1 in 20 times according to your comment), 95% of the work is to figure out what triggers the bug. I've done that 95% for you. Now you just need to do the 5% to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @user3386109 i tried your NULL NULL approach, now only the first 2 values are processed, not the last 3.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my loop to this:

```
  char *array[4];
  char separator[] = ":";
  char *segmentPointer = strtok((char*)buf, separator);
  int i = 0;
  if ((segmentPointer[0] == '1') && (segmentPointer[1] == '\0')) {
    segmentPointer = strtok(NULL, separator);
    while (segmentPointer != NULL) {
      array[i] = segmentPointer;
      i++;
      segmentPointer = strtok(NULL, separator);
    }
  }
```

The loop now works as expected reliably!